# Stata: Creating Date Dummies from Start and End Date

Tags: stata

I would like to create from some start and end dates dummy variables which take value 1 if in the range. For example, from

```
id    start     end
1     01072014  05072014
1     05012014  06012015
```

I would like to get

```
id    start     end       d_01012014  d_02012014 d_03012014 ... d_01052014 ... d_31122014
1     01012014  02012014  1           1          0              0              0
1     01052014  02052015  0           0          0              1              0
```

So that I eventually can reshape long my data, dropping all observations out of dayrange.
My idea was to use a loop with stata date format, somethin like this:

```
foreach i in *stataformat startdate*/*stataformat enddate* {
generate d_`i'=1 if `i'>=start & `i'<=end
}
```

But the problem from this method is that my variables would alle have incomprensible names. So do you either suggest another approach, or have an idea how to rename variables containing stata datecodes to 'understandable' names?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you give a complete macro? I don't know what you put in for the *stataformat startdate*. A potential workaround is to change your dates into "number of days/weeks elapsed from a reference date." And another one (I haven't verified) is to extract the month, day, and year from each i, and concat them together as your variable name.

Comment: The internal Stata format for dates (not date and time) is days in 1-1-1960, so that is already in the form sugested by @Penguin_Knight

Answer (score 5):

If I wanted to do this from first principle I would start with long format data:

```
clear
input id  spell  str10 start   str10 end
      1   1      "01-07-2014"  "05-07-2014"
      1   2      "06-08-2014"  "06-01-2015"
end

gen start2 = date(start, "MDY")
gen end2 = date(end, "MDY")

format start2 %td
format end2 %td

sum start2
local min = r(min)
sum end2
local range = r(max) - `min' + 1

expand `range'
bys id spell : gen date = `min' + _n - 1
format date %td
keep if date >= start2 & date <= end2
```

However, since this is probably survival analysis data, and you already `stset` the dataset (or you are going to), you can just use `stsplit`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works well for me. Now it gets a bit tricky. For each spell I have a monthly income figure for one year. I would like to know income per day when start and end are employment dates. Across spells, employment dates can overlap. I would like to have a long result, such that each observation is a day worked, indicating total daily income (from all spells) and maximum income at each day as well as spell so that I can tell which was the main source of income at that day. Any hints how I can use your proposal for that? I have no idea what survival analysis means by the way.